# Why do I get "Error: `...` is not empty" in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm a Python guy who is asked to run some R code that returns the following error:

> Error: `...` is not empty.
>
> We detected these problematic arguments:
>
> - `..1`
>
> These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
> Did you misspecify an argument? Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where
> the error occurred.

I could reduce the code to this MWE:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(1)
x %>% ungroup(x)
```

I have no idea what line 3 is supposed to do, but it fails on my system (dplyr 1.0.0), while working using dplyr 0.8.5 or on https://rdrr.io/snippets/, where it prints

```
  X1
1  1
```

I have tried a number of things, with no success:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE)
remove.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("dplyr")
```

What is going on here? How can I (help) investigate?

**Update**: `options(error = recover)` gives me this:

```
 1: x %>% ungroup(x)
 2: withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
 3: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
 4: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
 5: `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
 6: freduce(value, `_function_list`)
 7: withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
 8: function_list[[k]](value)
 9: ungroup(., x)
10: ungroup.data.frame(., x)
11: ellipsis::check_dots_empty()
12: action_dots(action = action, message = "`...` is not empty.", dot_names = n
13: action(message, .subclass = c(.subclass, "rlib_error_dots"), ...)
14: signal_abort(cnd)
```

**Another update**: the [complete line of code](https://github.com/lujunyan1118/DrugScreenExplorer/blob/00828da03c059913dcd76a2909c574be6e30aed4/R/importData.R#L221), non-minimized, if that matters, is

```
screenData <- mutate_if(screenData, is.character, as.factor) %>% ungroup(screenData)
```

Maybe that makes more sense than my MWE.

**Another one**: `dput(screenData)` returns

```
structure(list(wellID = "A001", rowID = "A0", colID = "01", value = 0, 
    fileName = "V3_Prob5_p1", batch = structure(NA_integer_, .Label = character(0), class = "factor"), 
    sampleID = NA, patientID = NA, name = NA_character_, concentration = NA_real_, 
    wellType = "sample"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Finally, I opened an issue with the maintainer of the code, see https://github.com/lujunyan1118/DrugScreenExplorer/issues/1,
and with `dplyr`, see https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5368

Comment: I receive this error when the package 'dplyr' is not loaded. Are you sure have installed and then correctly loaded dplyr with `library(dplyr)`

Comment: following ljwharbers comment, try :
x <- data.frame(1) ;
x %>% dplyr::ungroup(x)

And tell us if it works

Comment: @ljwharbers What? No. When the package is not loaded, you’ll get a different error (“could not find function ‘ungroup’”).

Comment: `x %>% ungroup(x)` runs `ungroup(x,x)`.

Comment: @LeonIpdjian without `library(dplyr)`, `%>%` cannot be found. With `library(dplyr)`, same error as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipe `%>%` is syntactic sugar.  It means "take the object on the left hand side of the pipe and use it as the first argument to the function on the right-hand side of the pipe".

So you can say `ungroup(x)` or `x %>% ungroup()`, both of which work, but `x %>% ungroup(x)` is trying to both ungroup a data.frame called `x` and remove a variable called `x` from the grouping of the data.frame called `x`.  But the data.frame `x` doesn't contain a variable called `x`.  Hence the problem.

The code you've been given is inherently wrong (or at the very least confusingly written).

**Update**
Following the post of your `dput`.

`screenData %>% ungroup(screenData)` is equivalent to `ungroup(screenData, screenData)` where the first `screenData` is the data.frame to ungroup and the second is the name of the variable in the data.frame to remove from the grouping.  but the data.frame `screenData` does not contain a column called `screenData`.  That's why you get an error.

The code you have been given is unequivocally incorrect.

The fact that it ran without error in a previous version of `dplyr` is purely accidental.

Comment: The first part of your answer is spot-on, but your explanation of what `ungroup` with multiple parameters does is wrong: as the error message says, `ungroup` simply does not take multiple arguments at all.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: From the online doc: "... 
In group_by(), variables or computations to group by. In ungroup(), variables to remove from the grouping.".  I also thought that `ungroup` took no other arguments until I checked.  [`dplyr` version 1.0.0]

Comment: Indeed. The error message for `data.frame` is apparently outdated, it wrongly states that `ungroup` takes no extra arguments.

Comment: I have updated the question: the original code did *not* have `x %>% ungroup(x)` [that was a result of me simplifying the code], but some `f(x) %>% ungroup(x)`. I don't know if that makes more sense, but I did want to point out that difference.

Comment: Then please post the results of `dput(screenData)` or `dput(head(screenData)` so that we can attempt to reproduce your problem.  At the moment, we can only give you theoretical suggestions.  Nevertheless, I agree with @KonradRudolph: `x %>% ungoup(x)` or equivalent is almosty certainly incorrect.

Comment: I'll put `dput(screenData)` into the question now.

Comment: So when I want to reproduce what dplyr 0.8.5 did for `ungroup(x, x)`, what should I run in dplyr 1.0.0 instead?

Comment: As both @KonradRudolph and I have said, `screenData <- mutate_if(screenData, is.character, as.factor) %>% ungroup()`.  This will work for both `dplyr` v0.8.x and v1.0.0 so you will also save yourself a maintenance task when your host upgrades to v1.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

The `ungroup` function takes no extra arguments. The code you’ve been provided with is wrong. Remove `x` from the `ungroup` call.

Comment: I am not sure this is correct, looking at page 30 of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf which shows `ungroup(x, ...)`. Also, the code does run without error on https://rdrr.io/snippets/

Comment: @bers This answer *is* correct in the context of your question, although Limey’s answer is better and more complete. Either way, the fact that the snippet runs on rdrr.io is because that website uses an outdated version of dplyr with a buggy `ungroup` implementation. That bug was subsequently fixed, hence the error message. Either way, the code you received *is* buggy. In fact, in the link you’ve posted, the entire `ungroup` call is redundant and should be removed.

Comment: So are you saying that "The `ungroup` function takes no extra arguments." is correct? What does the ellipsis mean then?

Comment: By the way, downgrading `devtools::install_version("dplyr", version="0.8.5")` fixed/circumvented/... the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I strongly urge you correct your code.  The issue is not fixed: you merely have two errors that cancel each other out.  You have buggy code that runs without error (rather than "works") purely by accident.  See my answer above.

Comment: @Limey I fully agree, I merely wanted to confirm Konrads hypothesis.

Comment: @bers `...` is (roughly) the equivalent of splat (`*` unpacking) in Python. However, `ungroup` is a *generic*, and the overridden method that you’re calling only accepts `...` arguments because it is required to, to satisfy the generic method interface; but calling it with `...` arguments is an error.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thank you very much! I missed the fact that I am looking at an overriden method here, probably due to the `data.frame`. That must be the "context" you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an issue with `tibble` package. [See here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/798).

Updating `tibble` solved the issue for me.

Comment: The error message is the same but the problem is unrelated. In fact, OP’s question predates the version of ‘pillar’ that caused the bug you’ve linked to.